# Missing Labels in Drupal Admin

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I've just noticed that all of my checkboxes and radio buttons are missing labels on my drupal site admin menus. Not sure when this started (I've checked several backups, and it is present in all of them), but I'd like to find a solution.

I have tried disabling modules, but to no effect at the moment.

I've attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJuMj.png)

I have noticed a couple of PHP warnings pop up on a couple of pages - these are:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set at offset 0 in /persistent/html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 1606
```

and

```
Warning: in drupal_clean_css_id![enter image description here][1]entifier() (line 3731 of /persistent/html/includes/common.inc).
```

Comment: Are you sure that text does not get rendered on page? Could be just CSS problem with visibility or color.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the source and get the following:<label class="option" for="edit-configurable-timezones"> </label>

Comment: Do you have any recurring notices or warnings in admin/reports/dblog?

Answer (score 0):

```
Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set at offset 0 in /persistent/html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 1606
```

was the clue apparently.

PHP had recently been upgraded from 5.3.13 to 5.3.14, and this seemed to change the way in which preg_match is handled. Upgraded again to 5.3.15 and the problem was still there - so I downgraded to 5.3.13 and the problem was solved.

Found other instances of people getting a similar preg_match error on Wordpress which subversion php upgrades!